# Ajax dropdown not working in mobile device

Tags: java

In my Java spring application I have a form with Region drop down. On selection of particular region city list is populated using ajax. This functionality working fine in web browsers.
But does not work from an iPhone or Android phone. The second dropdown is not populate.
Is any solution for such problem ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my bets are on the Javascript code not being compatible with the mobile browsers. Or on Javascript being disabled there.